# ASP.NET GridView e.NewValues == e.OldValues

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

Why would a GridView control's RowUpdating/RowUpdated event arguments have NewValues == OldValues regardless of user input?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to this now after some poking and rearranging.

Seemingly it was a DataBind in page load that was resetting the new values to the old ones before the event handler. Should have guessed.... :)

Comment: I'm not so sure you should have guessed that... That is one terrible code smell if you ask me.